# What does 's stand for in "America's got talent"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does *'s* stand for in "America's got talent"?

Does it stand for HAS? --> "America has got talent." Is this *'s* necessary? Is it incorrect to say "America got talent"? For example, ABC is a school name, and it wants to hold a talent show. **"ABC got talent."** Is it incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the 's stands for "has" and it required for the sentence to be gramatically correct with the meaning you want.

Comment: No, it's not required. Although it doesn't *mean* the same thing, and it's not what would normally be written, *America got talent* is still grammatical. (It's the same thing as the difference between *the dog got a ball* as opposed to *the dog has got a ball*.) In this case, *America got talent* would mean that America went out and got talent—not that it currently possesses it.

Comment: I believe the combination "have got" in place of "have" is largely an Americanism.

Comment: @GEdgar: I believe you are wrong about that. [See this British Council web page about *have got*](http://learnenglishteens.britishcouncil.org/grammar/beginner-grammar/have-got).

Comment: As @JasonBassford notes, *America Got Talent* would be the simple past of what in the perfect would be *America Has Gotten Talent*. The differing uses of *got*, *have*, and *gotten* for possession and for acquisition are a key distinction between British and North American Englishes, and each sounds grating to the other.